# "Complement" of a Ferrer's diagram

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

If I have the Ferrer diagram of 1+2+4:

[image]

and derive the diagram which "fills the empty space", so:

[image]

i.e. the complement of the rows, fitting into a $3 \times 4$ box,
so that, "united" together, the two diagrams form a rectangle,

[image]

what is this diagram called? It is a sort of complementary diagram. Is there a name?

Comment: edited, sorry indeed it is a rectangle

Comment: In my experience, if the original partition/diagram is $\lambda$, it’s simply called the complement of $\lambda$ in a $3\times 4$ rectangle.